# Angular 2: Manually bootstrap component not part of root component with data

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

I have a component I'd like to initialize and render apart from the main bootstrap application.

In react, for instance, I can do something like this:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
React.render(React.createElement(MyComponent, { }), div);
```

I'd like to be able to do something similar in Angular 2 with a component.

Also, I realize in angular terms, these components might also be considered directives. I'm not quite sure if I should be using the directives or component terminology in this scenario.

Here is example code for what I am doing now(I've tried to trim down as much as possible):

```
export interface Tweet {
  id: number;
  text: string;
}
@Component({
    selector: 'tweet',
    template: `
{{tweet.text}}
`,
    inputs: ['tweet']
})
export class TweetComponent {
  public tweet: Tweet;
}

// This works when in the context of another component's template like:
<tweet [tweet]="tweet"></tweet>

// code to manually initialize
var tweetEl = document.createElement('tweet');
var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.appendChild(tweetEl);
var comp = new TweetComponent();
comp.tweet = tweet;
bootstrap(TweetComponent, [provide(TweetComponent, {useValue: comp})]);
```

Right now, it is giving me the following error:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined in
>   {{tweet.text}} in TweetComponent]

Comment: Looks like you are trying something like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7136 or https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/915

Comment: Coming from more of a react background, it's rather insane this isn't possible and easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can run bootstrap twice.

```
bootstrap(ComponentA);
bootstrap(ComponentB);
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass a parameter to it that way? The component depends on model instance. Also, it would be nice to be able to specify the DOM element to run it against instead of it running against the whole DOM.

Comment: It's "run against" the selector the component contains in it's `@Component({selector: 'comp-a', ...})`. You can pass parameters using the providers list in `bootstrap(ComponentA, [provide(Config, {useValue: new Config('someValue')})])`

Comment: grrr, unfortunately, it doesn't seem like it is initializing the component correctly. Even thought I instantiate the component and set the values appropriately for it, in the template, it doesn't get the correct public properties from the component instance. Still digging...

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what your doing. I'm pretty sure this just works fine if done right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my really hacky way to do it for now until someone posts a better answer.

First off, split the target component off into a base component and then 2 sub components, one like the original and the second with a constructor like this:

```
constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, elementRef: ElementRef) {
  this.data = elementRef.nativeElement.attributes['data'];
}
```

Then, to manually bootstrap the component::

```
var el = document.createElement('myselector');
el.attributes['data'] = data;
var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.appendChild(el);
bootstrap(MyComponent)
```

Comment: FYI DynamicComponentLoader was removed before 2.0 was released